# Stack Implementation of a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I'm having issues with the following program, in particular the read function, where I'm reading in data from a text file and building a stack based off the data. I have comments in the function so you can see my thought process. What happens is when I use the display function the program just keep repeating the last entry in an infinite loop. I appreciate any recommendations to my code, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Struct for linked list node
struct produceItem
{
    char produce[20];
    char type[20];
    char soldBy[20];
    float price;
    int quantityInStock;
    struct produceItem *next;
};

// Function to read in data from file to
void read(struct produceItem **top)
{
    struct produceItem *temp = NULL;

    temp = (struct produceItem *)malloc(sizeof(struct produceItem));

    char line[50];
    char *value;

    FILE *data;

    data = fopen("RecitationFiveInput.txt", "r");

    printf("Trying to open file RecitationFiveInput.txt\n");

    if (data == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file RecitationFiveInput.txt\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), data))
        {
            value = strtok(line, ", ");
            strcpy(temp->produce, value);

            value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
            strcpy(temp->type, value);

            value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
            strcpy(temp->soldBy, value);

            value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
            temp->price = atof(value);

            value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
            temp->quantityInStock = atoi(value);

            temp->next = NULL;

            // the stack is empty
            if (*top == NULL)
            {
                *top = (struct produceItem *)malloc(sizeof(struct produceItem));
                *top = temp;
            }

            // there is at least one node on the stack
            else
            {
                // set the new nodes pointer to look at top
                temp->next = *top;
                // reset top to be temp so it is the top of the stack again
                *top = temp;
            }
        }

        printf("Successfully opened file RecitationFiveInput.txt\n");
    }

    fclose(data);

    return;
}

// Function to display the nodes of the linked list that contains the data from the data file
void display(struct produceItem *top)
{
    int value = 1;

    struct produceItem *top1;

    top1 = top;

    printf("=============================================================================\n");
    printf(" Item #   Produce          Type          Sold By          Price      In Stock\n");
    printf("=============================================================================\n");

    if(top1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        while(top1 != NULL)
        {
            printf("   %d      %s            %s        %s            %.2lf         %d\n", value, top1->produce, top1->type, top1->soldBy, top1->price, top1->quantityInStock);
            value++;

            top1 = top1->next;
        }
    }
    return;
}

//Main function
int main()
{
    int input = 0;

    struct produceItem *top;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nList Operations\n");
        printf("=================\n");
        printf("1. Stock Produce Department\n");
        printf("2. Display Produce Inventory\n");
        printf("3. Reverse Order of Produce Inventory\n");
        printf("4. Export Produce Inventory\n");
        printf("5. Exit Program\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");

        if(scanf("%d", &input) <= 0)
        {
            printf("Enter only an integer.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            switch(input)
            {
                case 1:
                    read(&top);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    display(top);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //function
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //function
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf("You have exited the program, Goodbye!\n");
                    return 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Invalid option.\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only stack involved in this program is the call-stack.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't familiar with the terminology, I'm pretty new to coding. Looked up what a call-stack is, glad I'm learning the vocabulary for it.

Comment: `temp = (struct produceItem *)malloc(sizeof(struct produceItem));` move into `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), data)) {... }`, because new node needs  each loop. also delete `*top = (struct produceItem *)malloc(sizeof(struct produceItem));`.

Comment: It looks like he has a stack implemented as a linked list. He pushed the newest items to the front of the list and reads these items from the front. IE in last in first out order. The order you'd expect from a list.

Comment: `if (*top == NULL)` in `read()`(bad name...) is undefined behavior, because `top` in `main()` is uninitialized.

Comment: BLUEPIXY is right. You don't create a new node for each element you want in the stack/list. If you only read in one node, you wouldn't see the infinite loop behavior. You create an infinite loop in the linked list by pointing tmp->next to top when top referenced the same node.

Comment: Yup, BLUEPIXY was correct, moving the malloc into the while loop and deleting the malloc for the top pointer resolved my issues. I was still having a crash problem, but that also turned out to be from the top pointer not being initialized in main as you pointed out EOF. Thank you all for the help, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: `char line[50];` is small for reading in data meant for `struct produceItem`.  Recommend at least 100.

Comment: "I apologize" -- no need; EOF is wrong. A linked list is one way to implement the stack abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your read function as below :
void read(struct produceItem **top)
{
    struct produceItem *temp = NULL;

```
//temp = (struct produceItem *)malloc(sizeof(struct produceItem));

char line[50];
char *value;

FILE *data;

data = fopen("RecitationFiveInput.txt", "r");

printf("Trying to open file RecitationFiveInput.txt\n");

if (data == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open file RecitationFiveInput.txt\n");
}
else
{
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), data))
    {
        temp = (struct produceItem *)malloc(sizeof(struct produceItem));
        value = strtok(line, ", ");
        strcpy(temp->produce, value);

        value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        strcpy(temp->type, value);

        value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        strcpy(temp->soldBy, value);

        value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        temp->price = atof(value);

        value = strtok(NULL, ", ");
        temp->quantityInStock = atoi(value);

 if (*top == NULL)
        {
            //*top = (struct produceItem *)malloc(sizeof(struct produceItem));
            *top = temp;
        }

        // there is at least one node on the stack
        else
        {
            // set the new nodes pointer to look at top
            temp->next = *top;
            // reset top to be temp so it is the top of the stack again
            *top = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("Successfully opened file RecitationFiveInput.txt\n");
}

fclose(data);

return;
```

}

and also set  struct produceItem *top = NULL; in main.
It is working fine.